# How to access index formatting as a string

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a panda dataframe that looks like this

```
|           | Column B |
| -- ------ | -------- |
| a index   | 2        |
| b index   | 4        |
```

i need it to look like this

```
|          | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| a        | 2        |
| b        | 4        |
```

how can i remove word "index" from the panda's index?

Comment: How did you generate the dataframe in the first place?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to avoid this in the first place, but assuming you can't, you can fix it with [`removesuffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html):

```
df.index = df.index.str.removesuffix(' index')
```

Or with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace(r'\s*index$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   Column B
a         2
b         4
```